# sencha 2.3 beta - Touch Grid is not working at run-time using sencha Architect v3.0

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect

When running the app.html, after publishing it using sencha architect 3.0, it shows the below error. In complie time am able to see the values populated in this Grid.

But the link seems to be empty in order to fetch the Grid.js for the new 2.3 beta version....

Please let me know any other way to resolve this error.

Error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)http://sc13-live.sencha.com/touch/touch-2.3.0/src/grid/Grid.js?_dc=1378814671364

// @require @packageOverrides
Ext.Loader.setConfig({

});

Ext.application({
    models: [
        'MyModel'
    ],
    stores: [
        'MyDirectStore'
    ],
    views: [
        'MyGrid'
    ],
    name: 'MyApp',

```
launch: function() {

    Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyGrid', {fullscreen: true});
}
```

});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Grid',

```
config: {
    height: 297,
    width: 444,
    store: 'MyDirectStore',
    title: 'Grid-5Cols',
    columns: [
        {
            xtype: 'column',
            width: 85,
            dataIndex: 'no',
            text: 'EmpNo'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'column',
            width: 89,
            dataIndex: 'name',
            text: 'EName'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'column',
            width: 86,
            dataIndex: 'sal1',
            text: 'Sal1'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'column',
            width: 86,
            dataIndex: 'sal2',
            text: 'Sal2'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'column',
            width: 80,
            dataIndex: 'sal3',
            text: 'Sal3'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyDirectStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

```
requires: [
    'MyApp.model.MyModel'
],

config: {
    data: [
        [
            '1',
            'AceSupplies',
            '05',
            '1000',
            '10'
        ],
        [
            '2',
            'BestGoods',
            '11',
            '2000',
            '20'
        ],
        [
            '3',
            'First Choice',
            '20',
            '3000',
            '30'
        ]
    ],
    model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
    storeId: 'MyDirectStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
}
```

});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

```
config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'no',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'sal1',
            type: 'float'
        },
        {
            name: 'sal2',
            type: 'float'
        },
        {
            name: 'sal3',
            type: 'float'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

Comment: publish your code, so others can assist you.

Comment: This application was done using sencha architect 3.0, with sencha touch 2.3 beta.

Answer (score 0):

The new Sencha Touch Grid is not included with standard Sencha Touch, please see below:

> Please note that the new Touch Grid component is not a part of Sencha
>   Touch and is only available as part of Sencha Complete or Sencha Touch
>   Bundle.

Source: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

Comment: Is there anyway we can add it to our sencha touch, i tried to add using Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true,
    paths   : {
        'Ext.ux.touch.grid': '/Ext.ux.touch.grid'
    }
});  and placed the folder under root directory.